# Output DataTable using StringTemplate

Tags: c#, datatable, stringtemplate

I'm trying to implement a method that will accept `DataTable` with `StringTemplate` and return string representation of data.

I found how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210792/438180) and [here](http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/stringtemplate-interest/2007-June/001115.html), but it doesn't work for me.

Example code:

```
// Here can be any table with any number of columns.
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("StrCol", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("IntCol", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Row1String", 1 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Row2String", 2 });

var data = from dataRow in table.AsEnumerable()
           select dataRow;

var st = new StringTemplate("$items:{$it.StrCol$ $it.IntCol$}$");
st.SetAttribute("items", data);
Console.Write(st.ToString());
```

Result:

```
Class DataRow has no such attribute: StrCol in template context [anonymous anonymous]
Class DataRow has no such attribute: IntCol in template context [anonymous anonymous]
Class DataRow has no such attribute: StrCol in template context [anonymous anonymous]
Class DataRow has no such attribute: IntCol in template context [anonymous anonymous]
```

**UPD:**

I have to use *Antlr3.StringTemplate.dll* version **3.1.0** of `StringTemplate`. I decided to try on another version and downloaded *Antlr3.StringTemplate.dll* version **3.3.0**. Everything works fine. So, is there any way to apply template on `DataTable` using old library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible workaround to use string templates on `DataTable` is to convert rows to collection of dictionaries, so it will be possible to access rows cells by column names:

```
var columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(col => col.ColumnName);
var data = from DataRow row in table.Rows
           select columns.ToDictionary(col => col, col => row[col]);

var st = new StringTemplate("$items:{$it.StrCol$ $it.IntCol$\n}$");
st.SetAttribute("items", data);
```

With newer version of `StringTemplate` library that works with `DataTable`:

```
var st = new StringTemplate("$items:{$it.StrCol$ $it.IntCol$\n}$");
st.SetAttribute("items", table.Rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

either shape your datarow:

```
select new { StrCol = dataRow["StrCol"], IntCol = dataRow["IntCol"] }
```

or adapt your StringTemplate (not sure if that works though)

```
var st = new StringTemplate("$items:{$it[0]$ $it[1]}$");
```

Comment: The issue that I can't hardcode anonymous type that way because my code should work with **any** `DataTable`.